# using name="something[]" in a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

In HTML i'm building a form, a simple list where you have to select types of medication (with checkboxes).
This list you can extend by clicking a plus icon that adds new checkbox AND hidden field to the list.

```
var addsoort = jQuery( ".add_drugs_veld" ).val();
                    var listart = '<li><input type="hidden" name="drugsoorten[][naam]" value="'+addsoort+'"/>';
                    listart += '<div class="checkbox">';
                    listart += '<input type="checkbox" id="'+addsoort+'" name="drugsoorten[][value]" value="<?php if($currentstep == '1') { echo "1"; }else{ echo "2"; }?>" checked/>';
                    listart += '<label for="'+addsoort+'"><span></span></label>';
                    listart += '</div>';
                    listart += '<div class="drugnaam">';


                    var liend = '</div>';
                    liend += '</li>';

                    if (jQuery(".add_drugs_veld").val() != "") {
                     jQuery('.test').before(listart + addsoort + liend);
                     jQuery( ".add_drugs_veld" ).val('')
                    }
```

Using the brackets like so: drugsoorten[][naam] extends my array and counts on, that's perfect. After that, drugsoorten[][value] counts on.. But this should be the same ID..

I think this is simple, but I dont have the knowledge yet.. Building a counter in the jquery script should be a solution, but i'd like to know how this is done with pure HTML if possible.

Comment: Not sure I get it, why would you want a counter when a pair of brackets without a counter automatically creates an array with the values, while a counter just messes things up with a different name for each element of the same type ?

Comment: @adeneo it's the opposite way around. Empty brackets create a new array for each field. Using a counter would fix that, but the asker doesn't like that solution.

Comment: The brackets count on each time they're used.. That's the problem, because i add two inputs each time

Comment: @JanDvorak - Didn't notice the second set of brackets, I almost never use this PHP "feature", but when I have used it I have only used one set of brackets, and PHP creates the array. I tend to create my forms in a way that this would never be an issue, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
<input type="hidden" name="drugsoorten_naam[]" ...
<input type="checkbox" name="drugsoorten_value[]" ...
```

And then server-side use

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['drugsoorten_naam']); $i++) {
    $_GET['drugsoorten_naam'][$i];
    $_GET['drugsoorten_value'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the solution since this changes the whole build of my array.. This would break rest of the script..

Comment: This _is_, generally, the way to go. Second, you did not post the rest of the script, you should, so we know what the limitations are. Third, the other solution would be, as @Jan Dvorak said, using a JavaScript counter (`name="drugsoorten[' + i + '][naam]"`).

Comment: Jep, the javascript counter seems to be the only solution.. I really thought there would be a simpler solution.. Thanks to all! @Sergiu; This is the best answer i can get. I let the rest of the code out because it would make things more messy than needed..